# Using OpenPyxl to dynamically create dictionaries?

Tags: python, excel, dictionary, openpyxl, defaultdict

I'm using Openpyxl to read an excel file, specifically one column, that looks like:

[this excel snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAXd0.png)

The number of main and sub classes in the source document can change, and my goal is to be able to iterate through and create perhaps a nested dictionary for each main class of the form:

```
main_Class1 = { 'subClass1': {'data': 'data_1'},
                'subClass2': {'data': 'data_2'}}
```

I'm open to any data type, so long as the info is connected like such.

I've though to have the Classes in column B, merge Main Classes into column A and Subclasses into column C, then hide A and C so I can separate main and subs to more easily iterate like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZ12v.png)

and tried:

```
mainClassList = []
mainClassDict = defaultdict(list)
activeClassList=[]

for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=2):
    activeClass ="" #supposed to update this at every 
                    #appropriate row
    if row[0].value is not None:
        activeClass=row[0].value
        mainClassList.append(activeClass)
        mainClassDict[activeClass]=[]
        activeClassList.append(activeClass)
    # add 2nd column entries to 1st column keys
    # would be better if these were nested dicts
    if row[0].value is None and row[1].value is not None:
        mainClassDict[activeClass].append(row[1].value)

#check to see things are being added and updated as needed    
print("main Class List:", mainClassList)
print("active classes;", activeClassList)
for key, value in mainClassDict.items():
    print(key, ' : ', value)
```

Comment: Please include your own code.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually solved with the following:

```
mainClassDict = {} #create an empty dictionary for each level
subClassDict = {}
for row in class_sheet.iter_rows(min_row=2): 
        #catch only row 1 values
        if row[0].value is not None:
            main = row[0].value
            mainClassDict[main]={}
            subClassDict[main]={}
        # if none in row 1, select row 2 value instead
        if row[0].value is None and row[1].value is not None: 
            subclasslist = []
            subclasslist.append(row[1].value)
            #create empty list for data 
            attributelist = [] 
            # populate data list from row of choice
            attributelist.append(row[...].value) 
            # populate dict from elements in list using nested for
            for key in subclasslist:         
                for value in attributelist:
                    subClassDict[main][key] = value
```